# Should I create separate table or have the information as columns in the same table

Tags: oracle, denormalization

Sorry for the title but I could not find anything better that could suit my needs. I'm designing the database of a Document Management (Circulation) application. There are two types of documents - A and B. I've created a table one for each. Any document independent from its type has Instructions information that has to be attached to it. Here are the details of the Instrcutions:

```
Executors (1 to many on another table)
Deadline
Target
```

I know that there's a one to one relationship between the document types and Instructions, so according to database normalization I should not have a separate table for it. But on the other hand I'll have to include the same columns in two different tables. What do you think?

P.S. I won't be able to create a foreign key constraint between Instructions table and the two other.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to normalize your design, here is a suggestion to do so. You should be able to create foreign key constraints. This is without the extra `Instruction` table since all documents will have the instruction details, stored in the `Document` table:

```
Executor
----------
ExecutorID


Document
----------
DocumentID
ExecutorID
Deadline
Target
-- other columns, relative to all documents


DocumentA
----------
DocumentID
-- other columns, relative only to documents of type A


DocumentB  
----------
DocumentID 
-- other columns, relative only to documents of type B
```

and their relationships:

```
              Executor
                /1
               /
              /
             /0..N 
         Document
         1/    \1
         /      \
        /        \
   0..1/          \0..1
 DocumentA      DocumentB
```

*Note: the only constraint not shown (and enforced) with the above design is that a document has to be of either A or B type (and not both.) This can be enforced as well, with a somewhat more complex design.